# Can we send data to controller till my array gets empty?

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have big array which exceed request object length so i am thinking to send data to controller in small data frames so that it will not get crashed on extending http request object limit and data will in after certain interval of time.....

```
var param = "&table=" + table; //remove first three charactor 'btn' from id
    param = param + "&tblheader=" + tblheader;


var request = $.ajax({
    url: '../Reports/SendReport?'+param,//action method url which defined in controller
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8'
});
```

controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendReport(string table, string tblheader)
        {
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All above way right to send data but when we are using

```
   var param = "&table=" + table; //remove first three charactor 'btn' from id
        param = param + "&tblheader=" + tblheader;


    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '../Reports/SendReport?'+param,//action method url which defined in controller
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8'
    });
```

then we are passing data as a parameter to the  $.ajax then it has a certain limit around param.length = 1600 then after $.ajax fail to execute

if you want to send huge data then you have to use View Model object and assign this values on data so it will work easily..
because as i m using Asp.net MVC ,in that view model is strongly bonded to  view.so we can assign .if nay having better soln please share

Answer (score 0):

I Thinks your url isnt validate :
check this code please :

```
var param = { Table: table
              Tblheader: tblheader }; //json data


var request = $.ajax({
    url: '../Reports/SendReport'
    data: param,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Json object and send using ajax

```
    var ajaxPostDatastr = '{"table":"' + table + '","tblheader":"'+tblheader+'" }';
var jsonData = JSON.parse(ajaxPostDatastr);
var request = $.ajax({
url: '../Reports/SendReport?'+param,//action method url which defined in controller
type: 'POST',
cache: false,

contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8',
 data: jsonData});
```

In controller use same as what you did right now.

Hope this will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can send large data via JSON. But you need to increase the maxlength of the json data in web.config.

Refer the post : [Getting "The JSON request was too large to be deserialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966328/the-json-request-was-too-large-to-be-deserialized)