# ajax call doesn't hit breakpoint but continues to success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this ajax call. This is the first time I'm experiencing this problem. First, the break point on my action is not being hit. Second, the success function is being executed. Third, the value of my storeList/data is the whole code of the whole body content. This might be caused of my action not being found.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/reports/GetStoreFranchiseList?franchiseId=' + franchiseId,
  success: function (storeList) {
    console.log(storeList);
    var appendStr = "<li><a href='#' onclick=changeStore('All', 'All')>All</a></li>";
    // $.each(storeList, function (k, v) {
    //   console.log(v);
    //   appendStr += "<li><a href='#' onclick=changeStore('" + v.Id + "','" + v.StoreName + "')>" + v.StoreName + "</a></li>";
    // });
    console.log(appendStr);
    $(".rptStoreDdl").html(appendStr);
    $("#rptStoreDdlDv").removeClass().addClass("btn-group");
  }
});
```

When I try uncommenting the each function, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '21748' in #<error>`

Obviously because the data is wrong. Any Ideas guys? Thanks!

EDIT:

Tried accessing it via fiddler and I'm getting this: `/Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=/reports/GetStoreFranchiseList`

This triggers my customer error for not found. I'm really not sure why my action is not found.

Controller action:

```
[InPrivate]
public class ReportsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetStoreFranchiseList(string franchiseId)
    {
        var data = new List<Store>();

        if(WebUser.Franchisees != null && WebUser.Franchisees.Count() > 0)
        {
            data = WebUser.Franchisees.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == franchiseId).Stores;
        }

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the `storeList` content

Comment: In your ajax call, specify the data type that you are expecting back from server. eg : dataType: "json" along with type and url

Comment: I tried using fiddler, and sadly i'm getting error/notfound?aspxerrorpath

Comment: i think the error is because the storelist is null.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think so, the problem now is, the controller/action path is not found.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely a silent exception is being raised.  I also encountered this exact same problem.  It is worth noting that, not all exceptions will trigger a run-time error, from the browser/client it may appear that a valid return type has been returned.  In my case, I was able to use the Intellitrace feature of Visual Studio to sniff out the following silent exception:

"The JSON request was too large to be deserialized"

That gave me the clues I needed to fix the issue via this other [Stack Overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10966328/1177611)

I suggest trying to use the Ultimate version of Visual Studio which comes with Intellitrace to see if some similar exception is interfering with your server side code and ultimately tricking the client into thinking a valid response was returned.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the url like this:

```
url: '../Reports/GetStoreFranchiseList?franchiseId=' + franchiseId,
```

OR

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetStoreFranchiseList","Reports")' + '?franchiseId=' + franchiseId,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck with this.

Comment: @ljpv14 Update it with your controller name

Comment: I think its because of the annotation `[InPrivate]` , its works fine for me.