# ASP.NET MVC4 Error during serialization or deserialization JSON - big data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonserializer, large-data

I am writing to you with an error in website: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Used technologies: C #,. NET FW 4.5, ASP.NET MVC4 and Lint to SQL, Kendo UI (grid for show result).

I would like to return (in terms of Json) a large set of data - actually I have 50,000 records (more than 250,000 records would not occur)

I try enlarge maxJsonLength and future enable compression in web.config - with same error:

```
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10485760"/>
      </webServices>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

Next I try rewrite return method in C# class - with same error:
a) default

```
public JsonResult GetResult()
{
  // execute query for get result
  var myBigData = from ......
      select new
      {
          .......
      };

  // return result
  return this.Json(myBigData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

b) rewriten (still error)

```
public JsonResult GetResult()
{
  // execute query for get result
  var myBigData = from ......
      select new
      {
          .......
      };

  // return result
  var jsonResult = Json(myBigData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
  return jsonResult;
}
```

To eliminate the mistakes I tried a smaller number of data - all is right:
Test which is correct: 1 - 10 of 6999 items

Best regards,
 Peter

Note: Unfortunately, I went through a lot of discussion (here), but without success, so I apologize for any duplicate topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [seems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/255bb9a4-ad57-4f4e-8d4a-f684cd1ecf18) that value from `web.config` is ignored, and according to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx) you have to explicitly create an instance of `JavascriptSerializer`

```
public ContentResult GetResult() 
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    var result = new ContentResult();
    result.Content = serializer.Serialize(data);
    result.ContentType = "text/json";
    return result;
}
```

At least it works for me :)

Comment: I've just found a better [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943727/jsonmaxlength-exception-on-deserializing-large-json-objects)