# "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property." when trying to convert a partial view to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting the error `"Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."` when trying to convert a MVC partial view to string when the payload exceeds the `MaxJsonLength` property.

How do I go about setting the MaxJsonLength property in this case?  I've tried setting the `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>` property in the web.config, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509721/jsonvalueproviderfactory-throws-request-too-large) post, but that doesn't have any effect. I am not entirely where to go from here and looking for a bit of a guidance.

The code errors on the `viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);` line below:

```
    protected string ConvertViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        string razorView = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewName)) return razorView;

        if (model != null && ViewData != null)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }

        if (ControllerContext != null)
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            if (viewResult != null)
            {
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);

                    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);

                    razorView = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        return razorView;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that is happening when you Render the view and not when you are returning the payload to the client?

Comment: Yes, it throws an exception on `viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);` line.  I have an override of the Json method in the base controller that, but that code isn't reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying cause of this was due to trying to load too large a result set into the Telerik Kendo grid within the partial view - the Kendo grid was throwing the exeception which is why it was being caught on the `viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw)` line.  The solution was to break the result set down into smaller manageable chunks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  How do you "break the result...into smaller manageable chunks"?