# Json string length exceeds maximum on asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying to display a telerik dropdownlist in a web forms page, with the following code

```
private void LoadCustomerControl()
   {
       try
       {
           IControlPanelPersistenceProvider persistenceProvider = new ControlPanelDatabaseProvider();
           List<CustomerDataGrid> customerCollection = persistenceProvider.ListCustomerGrid(false);
           if (customerCollection != null && customerCollection.Count != 0)
           {
               cboCustomer.DataSource = null;
               cboCustomer.DataSource = customerCollection;
               cboCustomer.DataBind();
           }
           else
           {
               //TODO add here message
               m_btnSubbmit.Visible = false;
               m_btnModifyCustomer.Visible = false;
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           string excep = ex.ToString();
           //TODO add log here
       }
   }
```

Thing is that the list I'm getting is very big and then it raises this error in the browser

> Exception message: Error during serialization or deserialization using
>   the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the
>   value set on the maxJsonLength property.

I have tried to add to the web config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644 "/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

I also tried to new up a javascriptserializer and set it's maxjsonlength to Int32.MaxLength, serialize the datasource and then deserialize back to the List of CustomerDataGrid but none work.

The call to that LoadCustomerControl is done via

```
if (Request.QueryString.Get("customerId") != null && Request.QueryString.Get("customerId").Length > 0)
           {
               //Is comming from CustomerPage, display the customer
               LoadCustomerControl();
               cboCustomer.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString.Get("customerId");
               cboCustomer.Text = GetCustomerName(int.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get("customerId").ToString()));
               m_btnModifyCustomer.Visible = true;
           }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to the appsettings
< add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483644" />

Comment: Forgot to mention that tried that as well, same luck

Comment: Look at this stackoverflow thread. Might help.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509721/jsonvalueproviderfactory-throws-request-too-large

Comment: Thanks a lot, saw it before asking. Spent hours on this already but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: I also read somewhere that you may need to set <add key=”aspnet:UpdatePanelMaxScriptLength” value="whatever value you want” /> in appsettings