# how to do Json form MVC model

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, serialization, model

I have this models, I try to serialize as Json

```
public class a
{
    public String Name{ get; set; }
    public String LastName{ get; set; }
}
```

I would to have a Json like this

```
{  
   id:1,
   name:'Name',
   description:'Erika'
},
{  
   id:2,
   name:'LastName',
   description:'Conor'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the class like

```
    public class YourClassName
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public String name{ get; set; }
    public String description{ get; set; }
}
```

then you have serialize it using below code :

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourClassName);
```

hope this helps !!!

Comment: This doesn't serialize a list

Comment: what about if that class has 100 porperties??

Comment: You can set the value for MaxJsonDeserializerMembers                      <appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />
</appSettings>

Comment: You can provide custom implemention for JsonValueProviderFactory as well [more info] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509721/jsonvalueproviderfactory-throws-request-too-large)

Answer (score 1):

```
    //declare a static list of a class to model
   static List<a> _results = new List<a>
            {
                new a{
                    id:1,
                    name:'Name',
                    description:'Erika'},
                 new a{
                       id:2,
                       name:'LastName',
                       description:'Conor'
                       }
           };
//then add this ActionResult Action in controller which will return JSON Data

public ActionResult ReturnJson()
 {
   return Json(_results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
    //Best of Luck
```

Comment: sorry, I will next time

Answer (score 1):

Change your class to include three properties

```
public class YourClassName
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public String name{ get; set; }
    public String description{ get; set; }
}
```

then

in whatever controller you are,
on top

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

in action

```
List<YourClassName> objs = new List<YourClassName>();

YourClassName obj = new YourClassName
{  
  id=1,
  name = "Name",
  description = "Erika"
};

YourClassName obj1 = new YourClassName
{  
  id = 2,
  name = "LastName",
  description = "Conor"
};

objs.Add(obj);
objs.Add(obj1);

var jasonSerializedObjs = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objs);
```

Comment: problem is what about if there are 100 registers, so it too long hardcode all these!!!

Comment: if there are 100 you need to put then in database, and then fetch the data from database;
i just showed you how to convert c# object to json object

Comment: sorry, i did not amwers good. I tried say 100 of properties in the Class  a